# Update current UI when receive notification

Tags: android, android-service, google-cloud-messaging, android-broadcast

I am developing chat type application using **GCM** concept. I succeeded to send message to my friends who are also registered and using my app. I am storing conversation in **SQLite** at both side. Means when sender sends message and receiver receives message then conversation is being stored at both sides. Now what I want, if chat GUI is opened with my 'X' friend and I send message to that friend 'X', and after few seconds if a new message arrives from the same friend 'X', then I can update GUI simultaneously

I came up with [this](http://www.websmithing.com/2011/02/01/how-to-update-the-ui-in-an-android-activity-using-data-from-a-background-service/) tutorial and successfully updated GUI. But my problem is, how can I come to know that with whom my current chat is going on? Means when message arrives then my GUI will be updated but if I receive message from my other friend 'Y' then GUI should not get updated (as chat GUI is opened with conversation of friend 'X'). It should be there in Notification and when I click on that notification then and only then chat with that 'Y' friend should be updated. How can I do this? I also come with this code to know which activity is on top.

```
 ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
 // get the info from the currently running task
 List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
 Log.d("topActivity", "CURRENT Activity : " +  taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName());
 ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
 componentInfo.getPackageName();
```

But not getting how to solve the problem. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Current chat page is associated with a user x or y. whenever you receive a message in gcm service you can update if the chat is from same user as the current chat page else you can update the current activity saying someother user has sent a message or if app is not runiing or in any activity, post a notification. Shared preferences can be used to set the current user's unique id, and current activity details so your gcm receiver knows what to do.

Comment: ya buddy... but the question is how to know that who is current sender and receiver???

Comment: put that info in message { from:'x', msg:'blah blah' }. you must have the info about who you are talking to ?

Comment: yes, let me tell u one more thing, I've also passed that name with message. so now when message will be received, first it will be stored in db at receiver side. so I think I need to check condition and compare that message name with last entry into db. if both r same then GUI should be updated else not... am I right abbiya???

Comment: no need to compare the last entry to the db.Use more uniq property to find the users instead of name. Find which activity the app is in and with which user. Based on the do the rest.

Comment: yes I know the current activity with above code (posted in my question) but if u r suggesting me not to go with my concept then how to know USER?

Comment: as @abiya mentioned, find a way to identify each user in your way. pass that along with the GCM message.

Answer (score 0):

you can create 1 method that is fillListchat() .when message arrive then that specific method call in thread and set GUI in handler.so whenever you open any of your friend list like x,y or z then this list will be updated by default..ok..i hope its useful to you...

Comment: Can u elaborate in detail @dipali?

Comment: I'm saying that can u explain in detail your idea.. I'm not getting what u want to explain. thank u...

Comment: In your gcmmessage receiver you have to call one method fillListchat()
.In this method ,data will be stored in db as well as gui will refresh   in on thread handler.

Comment: yes, chat history is what I send and receive will be append to text of custom Listview

Comment: and please have a look at my comment which I just posted on abbiya's answer and let me know will it be right manner to do this ???